# Expression of type Iterator[A] doesn't conform to expected type Iterator[A]

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, tree, iterator, iterable

I'm a total beginner in scala and I have a very simple code which implements a tree. I would like to make it Iterable, so that I can use iterator to go through every element in this tree. Unfortunately, IntelliJ shows error.

> Expression of type Iterator[A] doesn't conform to expected type Iterator[A]

Which refers to iterator method in Node class.
Below my code:

```
abstract class MyTreeItem[A] extends Iterable

case class EmptyLeaf[A]() extends MyTreeItem[A] {
  override def iterator: Iterator[A] = Iterator.empty
}

case class Node[A](left: MyTreeItem[A], right: MyTreeItem[A], item: A) extends MyTreeItem[A] {
  *override def iterator: Iterator[A] = Iterator.single(item) ++ left.iterator ++ right.iterator*
}
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is adding the generic parameter when implementing `Iterable`:

```
abstract class MyTreeItem[A] extends Iterable[A]
```

Without it, `MyTreeItem[A]` is of type `Iterable[Any]` and concatenating iterators on your last line has infered type also `Iterable[Any]` which is, of course, not assignable to `Iterable[A]`.